# Magento - Adding to the Layout

Tags: magento

I have this section in one of my layout files:

```
<blog_post_view>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="blog/post" name="post" template="aw_blog/post.phtml" />
        <block type="socialbookmarking/bookmarks" name="bookmarks" template="bookmarks/bookmarks.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</blog_post_view>
```

This first block shows a post and the second block shows some social bookmarking icons.  The problem is the section which displays the post also displays the 'add comments' section.  I want to add the social icons between the post and the comments.

How can I do this?  Ie. add the Social block in the middle of the Post block?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it to:

```
<blog_post_view>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="blog/post" name="post" template="aw_blog/post.phtml">
            <block type="socialbookmarking/bookmarks" name="bookmarks" template="bookmarks/bookmarks.phtml"/>
        </block>
    </reference>
</blog_post_view>
```

and then inside the post template (aw_blog/post.phtml) put the following where you want the bookmark-things to appear:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('bookmarks'); ?>
```